# Limit of $\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+3}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

We have to evaluate: 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+3}\right)^x$$

---

**My work**:

Let the desired limit equal a constant $L$.

When I take $\log$ of both sides, the exponent $x$ comes down. What do I do now? Where will we apply L'Hopital's rule? Can we do it without the rule also?

The answer is $e^4$.

Comment: In your next step, move the $x$ to the denominator as $1/x$ to make a $0/0$ fraction and use L'Hospital's.

Comment: It becomes too much complicated? And still no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\ln\left(\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+3}\right)^x\right)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(x(\ln(x^2+5x+3)-\ln(x^2+x+3))\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\ln(x^2+5x+3)-\ln(x^2+x+3)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$\stackrel{\text{L'Hop}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{2x+5}{x^2+5x+3}-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+3}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{x^2(2x+1)}{x^2+x+3}-\frac{x^2(2x+5)}{x^2+5x+3}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{4x^2(x^2-3)}{(x^2+x+3)(x^2+5x+3)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{4(1-\frac{3}{x^2})}{(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2})(1+\frac{5}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2})}=4$$

Comment: But the answer is $e^4$

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal The final number is the natural logarithm of your limit.

Comment: Just the answer I wanted!

Answer (score 4):

You can do so: 
$$\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+3} = 1 + \frac{4x}{x^2+x+3}\sim 1 + \frac 4x$$
at $x=\infty$ and therefore 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+3}\right)^{\!x} =
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac 4x\right)^{\!x} = e^4$$

Comment: Can you plz give a more rigorous proof?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal It *is* rigorous!

Comment: You forgot the power $x$ in the first limit of the last line.

Comment: @anderstood, thanks

Comment: As it is not the case in general that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ implies $f(x)^x\sim g(x)^x$, to make this rigorous requires more justification of the second to last equals sign, doesn't it? @egreg

Comment: @egreg, you are right; but in this case, $\frac{x^2+5x+3}{x^2+x+2}\sim 1+\frac{4}{x} - \frac{4}{x^2}$, and all is well

Comment: Use $\ln(  (1+ A)^x ) = x \ln(1+A)$ first. Here $A$ is the fraction. Next use $\ln(1+A)\sim A$ for small $A$. Combine it with Michael Galuza's answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{4x}{x^2+x+3}\right)^{\dfrac{x^2+x+3}{4x}}\right]^{\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4x^2}{x^2+x+3}}$$

Set $\dfrac{x^2+x+3}{4x}=n$ in the inner limit to find $=e$ as $x\to\infty,n\to\infty$

and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4x^2}{x^2+x+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac4{1+\dfrac1x+\dfrac3{x^2}}=\cdots$

Answer (score 2):

look at how  $\frac{x^2 + 5x + 3}{x^2 + x + 3} $ behaves for large $x.$

we have 
$$ \frac{x^2 + 5x + 3}{x^2 + x + 3} = 1 + \frac{4x}{x^2 + x+3} = 1 + 4x(x^2 + x+3)^{-1} = 1 + 4x\left(x^{-2} -x^{-4}(x+3) + \cdots \right) = 1 + \frac4x + \cdots$$

therefore $$\left(\frac{x^2 + 5x + 3}{x^2 + x + 3} \right)^x = \left(1 + \frac4x+\cdots\right)^x = e^4 \text{ as } x \to \infty.$$

Comment: How did you change $(x^2+x+3)^{-1}$ to that? And how did you deduce that in the end?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal., $\frac1{x^2 + x+3} = (x^2 + x + 3)^{-1}.$  then use the binomial theorem $(big + small)^{-1} = big^{-1} - big^{-2}\, small + \cdots $

Comment: Nice use of expansion. The way I did it in my head was lazy division of $x$. Nearly hitting the 20k mark :).

Comment: @Chinny84, thanks. good to see you active again. seen any nice nonlinear differential equation?

Comment: Sadly not so much. not many exciting ones (just the multiply by $\dot{y}$ and reduce :(. I am working on my own nonlinear ode from my thesis (I would share it on here with more accomplished mathematicians such as yourself, but I am being selfish ;) ).

Comment: @Chinny84, i would love to see it. my summer break starts in a week. i will have lots free time to spend on math.

Comment: Ok. Send my a message via my email on my profile blog bit. I will put together something and attach some of the perturbation/expansion methods that me and the super came up with to solving them (or I will just email the differential equation ha)..look at Lienard odes and also Abel ode of the second kind.